# Graphite storage-aggregation.conf regex scope

Tags: metrics, graphite, graphite-carbon

I have had a good read through the doc on this but am still none the wiser.
http://graphite.readthedocs.io/en/latest/config-carbon.html

If we have a metric like so:

> /var/lib/graphite/whisper/p1/p2/account/count_num_events.wsp

Does anyone know for sure exactly what part of this path graphite is applying the storage-aggregation regex to?

I assume that it will be just

> "count_num_events"

and as such I could use a regex "^count.*" to match it. Or will it be applied to all or part of the rest of the path?

Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct. that will be the thing you need. BUT note the metric will be using dots not slashes

```
p1.p2.account.count_num_events
```

So what you'll need in storage-aggregation is any of the following

```
*count_num_events
p1.p2.*.count_num_events
p1.*.account.count_num_events
*.account.count_num_events
*.count_num_events
*count_num_events$
p1.p2.account.count_num_events
```

Answer (score 0):

I have finally got round to doing some testing on this.

Thanks for the answer Fred S I wish I had seen the response before doing the testing, would have helped.

So the answer is that graphite matches on the full metric name which is . separated.  Which for the example metric file:

> /var/lib/graphite/whisper/p1/p2/account/count_num_events.wsp

Would be:

> p1.p2.account.count_num_events

So the most strict regex you could do would be:

> ^p1\.p2\.account\.count_num_events$